# Assembly Language output displaying label twice

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I wrote the following. Everything works as I'd like it to except when it displays the credits still needed, it displays the label "Credits needed to graduate" twice. I'm new to assembly (and programming tbh), and try as I might I can't find anything to explain it.

While I'm at it, is this part repetitive?:

mov needCredits, eax

mov eax, needCredits; compute credits needed

```
.586
.MODEL FLAT

INCLUDE io.h

.STACK 4096 ; reserve 4096-byte stack

.DATA ; reserve storage for data

; all prompts
promptName BYTE "Enter your name", 0
promptDegree BYTE "Enter your degree", 0
promptCredits BYTE "How many credits have you taken towards your degree?", 0
promptRequired BYTE "How many credits are required for your degree?", 0

;all variables
studentName DWORD 40 DUP (?); holds value for student name
degree DWORD 40 DUP (?); holds degree name
creditsDone DWORD ?; holds credits taken
needCredits DWORD ?; holds credits required in degree program
string BYTE 40 DUP (?);
difference BYTE 11 DUP (?); holds calculation for credits still needed

;all output
resultLbl BYTE "Credits needed to graduate", 0

.CODE     ; start of main program code
_MainProc PROC 
    input promptName, studentName, 40; ask for student name
    input promptDegree, degree, 40; ask for degree
    
    input promptCredits, string, 40;
    atod string
    mov creditsDone, eax
    
    input promptRequired, string, 40;
    atod string
    mov needCredits, eax

    mov eax, needCredits; compute credits needed
    sub eax, creditsDone; 
    dtoa difference, eax
    
    output resultLbl, difference

    mov eax, 0
    ret
    
_MainProc ENDP
END  ; end of source code
```

[image]

Comment: What is in `io.h`? What does `output` do? Isn't the first line just the title for the dialog?

Comment: I don't think I'm understanding your question about the first line.

in io.h: ```output      MACRO  outLbl, outStr      ; display label and string
```

Comment: Your problem could be that `dtoa` does not zero terminate the `difference` so printing continues on to the `resultLbl` which happens to be after it. Maybe if you use `12 DUP (0)` it will work. Alternatively, `11 DUP (?), 0`